# what(): No such node json boost

Tags: json, boost, boost-propertytree

**I am trying to parse below JSON file using boost::property_tree.**

```
{
    "pi": 3.141,
    "temp": 3.141,
    "happy": true,
    "name": "Niels",
    "nothing": null,
    "answer": {
        "everything": 42
    },
    "list": [
        1,
        0,
        2
    ],
    "object": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": 42.99
    }
}
```

**But for second node 'temp', it is giving an error-**

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path>'
  what():  No such node (temp)
Aborted (core dumped)
@ubuntu:~/git_
```

**Have written code like below-**

```
std::ifstream file(jsonPath, std::ifstream::binary);
  using json = nlohmann::json;
  namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
  pt::ptree root;
  pt::read_json(jsonPath, root);  // Load the json file in this ptree 
  string valPi = root.get<string>("pi");  
  string valtemp = root.get<string>("temp");
```

Comment: shouldn't you be using `root.get<float>`?

Answer (score 2):

Boost Property Tree is not a JSON library.

Why would you (ab)use it, if you already have `nlohmann::json` included?

Your selector paths may not match the JSON. It's hard to tell because the example you show works correctly:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bee75eccd80a3fe)**

Prints

```
{
    "pi": "3.141",
    "temp": "3.141",
    "happy": "true",
    "name": "Niels",
    "nothing": "null",
    "answer": {
        "everything": "42"
    },
    "list": [
        "1",
        "0",
        "2"
    ],
    "object": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "42.99"
    }
}
Yay 3.141 and 3.141
```

No problem.

> Note, however, how all type information is lost, which is merely scratching the surface of "limitations" in PropertyTree: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.json_parser

## Use Boost JSON

Get serious:

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto root = boost::json::parse(R"({
    "pi": 3.141,
    "temp": 3.141,
    "happy": true,
    "name": "Niels",
    "nothing": null,
    "answer": {
        "everything": 42
    },
    "list": [
        1,
        0,
        2
    ],
    "object": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": 42.99
    }
})");

    std::cout << root << "\n";
    auto valPi   = root.at("pi").get_double();
    auto valtemp = root.at("temp").get_double();

    std::cout << "Yay " << valPi << " and " << valtemp << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
{"pi":3.141E0,"temp":3.141E0,"happy":true,"name":"Niels","nothing":null,"answer":{"everything":42},"list":
[1,0,2],"object":{"currency":"USD","value":4.299E1}}
Yay 3.141 and 3.141
```

### Using [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1aeqPP)**

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto root = nlohmann::json::parse(R"({
    "pi": 3.141,
    "temp": 3.141,
    "happy": true,
    "name": "Niels",
    "nothing": null,
    "answer": {
        "everything": 42
    },
    "list": [
        1,
        0,
        2
    ],
    "object": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": 42.99
    }
})");

    std::cout << root << "\n";
    auto valPi   = root["pi"].get<double>();
    auto valtemp = root["temp"].get<double>();

    std::cout << "Yay " << valPi << " and " << valtemp << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
{"answer":{"everything":42},"happy":true,"list":[1,0,2],"name":"Niels","nothing":null,"object":{"currency"
:"USD","value":42.99},"pi":3.141,"temp":3.141}
Yay 3.141 and 3.141
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string valPi = root.get<string>("pi");
```

This should be changed to :

```
 std::string valPi =root.get<std::string>(pt::ptree::path_type{"pi"});
```

if you would like the 2nd level:

```
 int answer_everything =root.get<int>(pt::ptree::path_type{"answer.everthing"});
```

or to be fancier using another delimiter :

```
int answer_everything =root.get<int>(pt::ptree::path_type{"answer\neverthing","\n"});
```